# pgfpages outer border instead of border shrink

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I'm using the `pgfpages` package to publish my handout. But I think the space between the pages is to big, whereas the space at the outer border is to small. How can I change this?
Currently I use this code:

```
\documentclass[compress,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\mode<presentation>
{
    % Präsentationsthema auswählen
    \usetheme{Boadilla}

    % äußeres Thema anpassen
    \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm, landscape]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 4}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your answer!
I expand your answer a little bit, so that it is possible to enter different length and not to think about ratios.
Now one can enter a page border and a BCOR length for the top. The border shrink now works as it should.

```
\documentclass[compress, handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[
          a4paper
        , border shrink=2mm
        , landscape
        , physical height=\paperheight%
        , physical width=\paperwidth%
        ]
\newlength{\pageborder}
\setlength{\pageborder}{5mm}
\newlength{\pageborderBCOR}
\setlength{\pageborderBCOR}{10mm}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{
          border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}
        , resized height=\dimexpr.5\pgfphysicalheight-\pageborder-.5\pageborderBCOR
        , resized width=\dimexpr.5\pgfphysicalwidth-\pageborder-.5\pageborderBCOR
        , center = \pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth+.5\pageborder}%
                                  {.75\pgfphysicalheight-.5\pageborder-.75\pageborderBCOR}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{
          border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}
        , resized height=\dimexpr.5\pgfphysicalheight-\pageborder-.5\pageborderBCOR
        , resized width=\dimexpr.5\pgfphysicalwidth-\pageborder-.5\pageborderBCOR
        , center = \pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth-.5\pageborder}%
                                  {.75\pgfphysicalheight-.5\pageborder-.75\pageborderBCOR}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{
          border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}
        , resized height=\dimexpr.5\pgfphysicalheight-\pageborder-.5\pageborderBCOR
        , resized width=\dimexpr.5\pgfphysicalwidth-\pageborder-.5\pageborderBCOR
        , center = \pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth+.5\pageborder}%
                                  {.25\pgfphysicalheight+.5\pageborder-.25\pageborderBCOR}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{
          border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}
        , resized height=\dimexpr.5\pgfphysicalheight-\pageborder-.5\pageborderBCOR
        , resized width=\dimexpr.5\pgfphysicalwidth-\pageborder-.5\pageborderBCOR
        , center = \pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth-.5\pageborder}%
                                  {.25\pgfphysicalheight+.5\pageborder-.25\pageborderBCOR}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 4}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Best regards
Dirk

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to give you the hint which options could be helpful. As you didn't state any explicit value, I just guessed some random values …

Comment: I didn´t think about explicit values, so that I expand your answer to my code, where I can easily play around with the values. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{<number>}{<options>}` macro (as you already did) where

- `<number>` is the logical number of the frame (1 is above left, 2 is above right, …) and
- `<options>` are options, e.g.

  - `resized width = <length>`
    width of the resulting frame, `<length>` can be given in a percentage of `\pgfphysicalwidth`.
  - `resized height = <length>`
  - `center = \pgfpoint{<x>}{<y>}`
    the center of the logical page, `<x>` and `<y>` can be given in a percentage of `\pgfphysicalwidth` and `\pgfphysicalheight` respectively.
  - `scale`, `xscale` and `yscale = <factor>`

This and more options are explained in the `pgfmanual` in the section “Defining a Layout” (currently 58.3).
Note, that I do not use the `resized …`options in the following example.

### Code

```
\documentclass[compress, handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper, border shrink=10mm, landscape]

\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth, 
  center = \pgfpoint{.3\pgfphysicalwidth}{.72\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
  center = \pgfpoint{.7\pgfphysicalwidth}{.72\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
  center = \pgfpoint{.3\pgfphysicalwidth}{.28\pgfphysicalheight}
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},
% resized height=.65\pgfphysicalheight,
% resized width=.65\pgfphysicalwidth,
 center = \pgfpoint{.7\pgfphysicalwidth}{.28\pgfphysicalheight}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Seite 4}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]